# Does azure storage folder supports disabling/restricting the ability to delete a folder

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Does azure storage folder supports disabling/restricting the ability to delete a folder in a container.  If no,  how to trigger an event off deletion that will automatically recreate the folder.

Answer (score 1):

1.Azure Blob storage does not have concept of folders. everything inside the container is considered a blob including the folders.
The hierarchy  is storage account>>container>>blob. Removing a particular folder is removing all the blobs which start with the folder name.

2.You can use custom RBAC roles to "Restrict user from upload or delete operation on Storage”   [Restrict user to delete blob](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-restrict-the-user-from-upload-download-or-delete-blob-in/ba-p/1078687)

We have few options available for end-to-end protection for blobs

1. **Container soft delete**, to restore a container that has been deleted.
2. **Blob versioning**, to automatically maintain previous versions of a blob. When blob versioning is enabled, you can restore an earlier version of a blob to recover your data if it is erroneously modified or deleted
3. **Blob soft delete**, to restore a blob or version that has been deleted

Comment: How do I setup an event using Azure powershell to trigger an email or auto create the deleted folder in my container

Comment: Restoring soft delete blobs using PowerShell you can refer this https://medium.com/microsoftazure/restore-a-soft-deleted-blob-with-powershell-411e643bef2f

Comment: To create an event for getting mail you have to create an azure function integrating it with storage  you can refer this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-notified-via-azure-event-grid-whenever-azure-blob-is-updated/